# Compiler Compliance and Issues in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, compatibility

I'm currently trying to write a simple EJB using Wildfly 17, jdk 1.8.0_211 and Eclipse 2019-06.

When I create EJB project and try to deploy in the server I got the following error

> ....has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

I found out that this is an issue with the compatibility between Java 11 and 8. So in order to fix I used the following method

- Right Click Project --> Properties --> Java Compiler and changed the "Compiler Compliance Level" from 11 to 1.8.
- I also made sure the "Execution Environment" matches the compliance level 1.8

Subsequent to this I was able to deploy my EJB. However, the Eclipse keeps on showing me an error icon which I do not know how to fix.

[image]

How to fix this issue? Any insights will be a great help.

Comment: *What* has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime? What's listed in the Problems view for your project?

Comment: I guess just triggering the target Java 1.8 when you already have a JDK 11 won't help since a lot of deprecated features in Java 8 are not in JDK 11 anymore, Try using real JDK 1.8 and run the app with it

Comment: @nitind I don't get the point.